# Adding rows of two categorical variables in a long dataset?

Tags: r, tidyverse, reshape2

I have a matrix in a long format (panel data) with several string variables, a categorical variable and a variable with numerical values.

The data contains information on output for several industrial sectors for countries at a given year. My idea would be to add two of those industry's for the same years within the same country, and change the name for the newly created industry.

For example, say I have the following matrix:

```
set.seed(10)

matrix <- cbind.data.frame(country = rep(c("aaa" , "bbb") , each = 6) , industry = rep(c("toys" , "paper") ,  each = 3 , times = 2) , 
                year = rep(c(2000:2002) , times = 4) , production = sample(0:100 , 12) )
```

that gives:

```
      country industry year   production
 [1,] "aaa"   "toys"   "2000" "8"       
 [2,] "aaa"   "toys"   "2001" "73"      
 [3,] "aaa"   "toys"   "2002" "75"      
 [4,] "aaa"   "paper"  "2000" "54"      
 [5,] "aaa"   "paper"  "2001" "71"      
 [6,] "aaa"   "paper"  "2002" "53"      
 [7,] "bbb"   "toys"   "2000" "38"      
 [8,] "bbb"   "toys"   "2001" "82"      
 [9,] "bbb"   "toys"   "2002" "87"      
[10,] "bbb"   "paper"  "2000" "14"      
[11,] "bbb"   "paper"  "2001" "91"      
[12,] "bbb"   "paper"  "2002" "41"
```

I would like to add the production from "toys" with the one from "paper" for each year and country and call the new industry "toys and paper" like so:

```
  year country       variable value
1 2000     aaa toys_and_paper    62
2 2000     bbb toys_and_paper    52
3 2001     aaa toys_and_paper   144
4 2001     bbb toys_and_paper   173
5 2002     aaa toys_and_paper   128
6 2002     bbb toys_and_paper   128
```

I know how to do this using reshape2 and tidyverse like so:

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)

test <- dcast(matrix , year + country ~ industry)

test <- test %>%
  mutate(toys_and_paper = paper + toys) %>%
  select(year , country , toys_and_paper)

test <- melt(test , id.vars = c("year" , "country"))
```

Is there a more direct way to do this?

Comment: If I understand this correctly you are adding by `year` and `country`. You can just use `mutate` to create the `variable` column with a constant value of `toys_and_paper`

Comment: Why do people use `cbind.data.frame`? I see no upside and only downside to using it in this context? Why not just use the `data.frame` function?

Comment: Adrian, why did you close [your recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68166248/3832970) as a duplicate of the post that is not actually answering your question?

Comment: oh sorry, it did in fact answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the original question has an example that is confusing since in the actual data set the there can be more industries.

Here's a toy data set with more than two industries

```
set.seed(10)

matrix <- cbind.data.frame(
   country = rep(c("aaa", "bbb"), each = 9),
   industry = rep(c("toys", "paper", "other"), each = 3, times = 2),
   year = rep(c(2000:2002), times = 6),
   production = sample(0:100, 18)
)
```

And a `dplyr` solution to the problem

```
matrix %>% 
   dplyr::mutate(
      industry = dplyr::if_else(
         industry %in% c("toys", "paper"), "toys_and_paper", industry
      )
   ) %>% 
   dplyr::group_by(
      year,
      country,
      industry
   ) %>% 
   dplyr::summarise(
      production = sum(production),
      .groups = "drop"
   )
```

If in the actual data set the `industry` column is a factor (and it should), then you can replace the `if_else()` statement for `forcats::fct_unify()`

Comment: In the case of your toy data, one can easily filter out `other` and then use any of the solutions mentioned.

Comment: The problem is that in the original toy data the other categories should have been included. I think the asker is looking to keep them and just group those two. If that is not the case then all answers are overkill since data would only need to be grouped by `year` and `country`, and then use `mutate` to add a constant.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

matrix %>%
  group_split(country, year) %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>%
            add_row(country = .x$country[1], 
                    industry = paste(.x$industry[1], "and", .x$industry[2], sep = "_"),
                    year = .x$year[1], 
                    production = sum(.x$production, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  filter(industry == "toys_and_paper") %>%
  arrange(year)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  country industry        year production
  <chr>   <chr>          <int>      <int>
1 aaa     toys_and_paper  2000         62
2 bbb     toys_and_paper  2000         52
3 aaa     toys_and_paper  2001        144
4 bbb     toys_and_paper  2001        173
5 aaa     toys_and_paper  2002        128
6 bbb     toys_and_paper  2002        128
```

Or this one which is a little less verbose:

```
matrix %>%
  group_by(country, year) %>%
  summarise(country = country[1], 
            industry = paste(industry[1], "and", industry[2], sep = "_"), 
            year = year[1], 
            production = sum(production, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: These options are dependent on the order in which the values of the `industry` column first appear in the data frame.

Comment: @Daniel yes you are right, I guess there remains some minor tweaks that the OP has to apply according to the configurations of the original data set. But I assumed there are not any more values other that `toy` and `paper` in `industry`, or at least the OP should've specified.

Comment: Agree. The original example data is not ideal. But the question does say: *data contains information on output for several industrial sectors*.

Comment: It's not a big deal, in that case if the op is only interested in these 2 categories all he needs is  `filter`ing the data.

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(
    production ~ .,
    transform(
        matrix,
        industry = ave(industry,
            country,
            year,
            FUN = function(v) paste0(v, collapse = "_and_")
        )
    ), sum
)
```

gives

```
  country       industry year production
1     aaa toys_and_paper 2000         62
2     bbb toys_and_paper 2000         52
3     aaa toys_and_paper 2001        144
4     bbb toys_and_paper 2001        173
5     aaa toys_and_paper 2002        128
6     bbb toys_and_paper 2002        128
```

Comment: This option does not work with more than two different values in the `industry` column and is dependent on the order in which they appear.